# Selenium Looped WebDriverWait

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Want to implement a `WebDriverWait` only once while in a nested for loop. Idea is to wait until it finds the price ($) or 5s then move on, but to do this only once in `for delta` loop and resets in `for d` loop. OK first iteration of `for d` loop however second iteration does not wait again. It enters `if delay` but doesn't perform the wait.

It looks like it doesn't wait again because it already performed this (the session code doesn't change?)? Do I need to iterate the wait variable? Is there a clean way to do this?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


for d in range (0, len(date_array)-duration_max):
    delay = True
    #Other Code

    for delta in range (duration_min,duration_max):

        try:
            if delay:
                wait =WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
                wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,"//*.../div[" + str(date_array[d + delta][2]) + "]/div/div[2]"), "$"))
                delay = False
        except:
            delay = False
            pass


        try:
            date_value = browser.find_element_by_xpath("...").text
            price_value = browser.find_element_by_xpath("...").text

        except:
            pass
```

The XPath called in the wait is always unique based on the d and delta index locations it pulls from date_array (not sure if this matters, just fyi).

Answer (score 0):

### Problem Explanation :

**Explicit wait**

They allow your code to `halt program execution`, or `freeze the thread`, until the `condition you pass it resolves`.

The `condition` is called with a `certain frequency` until the `timeout` of the wait is `elapsed`. This means that for as long as the condition returns a `falsy` value, `it will keep trying and waiting.`

> Since explicit waits allow you to wait for a condition to occur, they
> make a good fit for synchronising the state between the browser and
> its DOM, and your WebDriver script.

### Where it went wrong ?

1. When you define a `WebDriverWait`, you can defined once and use the reference everywhere in your code.
2. `text_to_be_present_in_element` is for :-

> """ An expectation for checking if the given text is present in the
> specified element."""

### Solution

1. Have a global `WebDriverWait`defined like below.
2. Use `visibility_of_element_located` instead of `text_to_be_present_in_element`.

**Code : -**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
for d in range (0, len(date_array)-duration_max):
    delay = True
    #Other Code
    for delta in range (duration_min, duration_max):
        try:
            if delay:
                some_text = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*.../div[" + str(date_array[d + delta][2]) + "]/div/div[2]"))).text
                assert some_text in "$"
                #wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//*.../div[" + str(date_array[d + delta][2]) + "]/div/div[2]"), "$"))
                delay = False
        except:
            delay = False
            pass


        try:
            date_value = browser.find_element_by_xpath("...").text
            price_value = browser.find_element_by_xpath("...").text

        except:
            pass
```

### Notes :

This will return a `web element.`

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*.../div[" + str(date_array[d + delta][2]) + "]/div/div[2]")))
```

so you can use `.text` or `.send_keys` etc just like you use it with `driver.find_element`